# How to convert whole object into Array when needed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Since long time am getting problem in this object to array and array to object. As i am working on external api - every codes are totally depend on the output from API

So here is my problem - Sometime am getting object (as there would be only single element in the result ) and sometime am getting a array with more than 2 or 3 items inside it, so when ever i perform some action like removing or manipulating or adding to single object am getting error on array and vise versa !

Whats the solution for this :(

Today i faced a problem:

Here is my object & Array :

```
//-------------Object--------------//
        "inventoryItems": {
            "age": "26",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "title": "Mr",
            "user" : "John"
        },
```

This is how i get from api when there is only one user presented,

```
//---------------Array-------------//

"inventoryItems": [
        {
            "age": "26",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "title": "Mr",
            "user" : "John"
         },
         {
            "age": "26",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "title": "Mr",
            "user" : "John"
         }
   ]
```

So, based on Array - i have created a map to miniplate the data but when it gets single object it throws error !

So, far :

I tried to add [] on object and it works - but when it comes to array it throws error as it will become nested array

Is there any industry practice for this problem ? Am sure developers would have found a great solution for this already !

Comment: What do you mean by "add [] on object"? How about `if (!Array.isArray(obj.inventoryItems)) obj.inventoryItems = [obj.inventoryItems]`? That way it always is an array.

Comment: For example - i just warped object with [] and it worked !

Comment: I also understand that i can "Array.isArray" but is that the convention ?@str

Comment: The proper convention would be to always return the same type (i.e. an array with zero, one, or more elements).

Comment: I belive your not getting my point ! Am using external api - so when i get data as single object either i need to convert it to array and implement code else i need to code for object also !

Comment: What do you mean by "*else i need to code for object also*"? If you ensure `inventoryItems` to always be an array, you can just work on that array (e.g. use loops or do whatever you need to on the *array*). In other words: there is no `else` case. Just always work with the array.

Comment: I know that, if its only going to be an arrya why am gonna post a question here ? At sometimes i get only single object and sometimes array ! So my question is how to handle that ? As i have implemented array.map function i cant do that on object !

Comment: I already told you twice in my previous comments, I even added a code example in my first comment. Not sure what else I can say.

Comment: Thank you ! How about using Array.flat()

Answer (score -1):

I think the best thing will be to make sure that your api provide an array in both cases so that when there is only on item your code will do the same action without crashing.

Though you can use a condition like this:

```
if (inventoryItems.length != undefined) {
  // This is an array
} else {
  // This is an object
}
```

Comment: "*This is an array*"–Not necessarily. An inventoryItem could very well have a `length` property.